# VBA, Excel: how to add a chart into a selected range

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range, addition

I am trying to add a chart into a range I have selected. Im running into some issues finding the proper way to do so. I there a way to do something along the lines of

```
Dim cht as ChartObject
Dim UserSelection as Range

Set UserSelection = ActiveSheet.Selection
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjectsy.Add(UserSelection)
```

trying to set the cht variable is throwing an error. I really looking for how to .Add into my selected range.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have `ChartObjectsy` or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: My guess is `ChartObjects.Add(UserSelection.Left, yourdesiredwidthinpoints)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```vb
Dim co, cht as Chart
Dim UserSelection as Range

Set UserSelection = ActiveSheet.Selection

'add a chartobject
Set co = UserSelection.Parent.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter)
co.Name = "myChart"
co.Top = UserSelection.Top 
co.Left = UserSelection.Left
co.Width = 400
co.Height = 400

Set cht = co.Chart 'the contained chart
```